# Leaderboard not found in Unity 2017.3.1f

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to add leaderboard for my game that I am planning to release on Android. I am receiving an error that says "Leaderboard not found" when I am trying to access Leaderboards in game. I am also getting another error which says that "Object reference is not set to an object" even though I double checked the name of the Leaderboards Button and I will specify the line where this error gets me. And I will also specify the the line that leaderboard error sends me. Here is the code that I wrote so far :

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LeaderboardController : MonoBehaviour {

public static LeaderboardController instance;

private const string ID = ".......";

public UnityEngine.UI.Button LeaderboardsButton;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    MakeSingleton();
    GetTheButton();
}

void GetTheButton()
{
    //this line is the problem about object reference.
    LeaderboardsButton = GameObject.Find("Leaderboards").GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
    LeaderboardsButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    LeaderboardsButton.onClick.AddListener(() => OpenLeaderBoardsScore());
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Start(){
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
}
void OnLevelWasLoaded()
{
    PostScore();
}
void MakeSingleton()
{
    if(instance != null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
public void OpenLeaderBoardsScore()
{
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI(ID);
    }
    else
    {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {

        });
    }
}
void PostScore()
{
    //this is the line that Leaderboard error sends me. 
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        Social.ReportScore(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score"), ID, (bool success) =>{

        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Confirm when you call GetTheButton function, the gameObject which name as "Leaderboards" is still in your scene. Maybe misspelling or the gameObject already destroyed.